# How to browse videos on YouTube without location bias?

Tags: youtube

On YouTube's [browse page](http://www.youtube.com/videos?feature=mh) I am shown the most viewed videos in my country. Even if I change my country in the settings, it will still show the same results. I would like to see the most viewed videos of each category without the location bias.

Comment: Where are you changing the settings ? The one at the bottom works. To prove it the most viewed video in Mexico : Ronaldinho vs Ronaldo.

Comment: Then again it might not be right for brazil I get : Old MacDonal had a farm.

Comment: @Philippe you found the answer but you posted it as comment

Answer (score 1):

As Philipe Harewood pointed out, it's not enough to change the country in the account settings, you must change it in the Browse page footer.

Answer (score 0):

i guess they are detecting your location through your public ip address, you can use [proxy](http://www.samair.ru/proxy/type-01.htm) web servers to over come this situtation

Comment: No, it doesn't uses the IP Geolocation, since the other answer works.